# Add static route on Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, route, interface

I have set up Ubuntu 14.04 server on a machine and configured /etc/network/interfaces with two gateways. The default one is em1 which is fine, but I need traffic to a specific IP address on the internet to be sent via the other gateway. The following command works from the command line:

```
sudo route add -net XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 172.16.0.1
```

but adding it to /etc/network/interfaces does not work on reboot:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
    address 10.0.2.251
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.2.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto em1:0
iface em1:0 inet static
    address 172.16.1.6
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 172.16.0.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

post-up route add -net XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 172.16.0.1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just for grins can you try it with a 30 bit (255.255.255.252) mask? I just found this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/560616/i-can-no-longer-add-a-static-route-for-a-single-host-with-32-subnet-mask-in-et that indicates it may be a problem with the 32 bit mask specifically. Not a fix but maybe more focus on the problem.

Comment: No dice. I changed the netmask but route complained
    route: netmask doesn't match route address

Comment: Well you would need to make it match for the network too. without knowing more of the IP I can;t tell what that should be.

Comment: Try putting it in the `iface em1:0` block, and try changing your `post-up` to an `up`.  You might also want to try the iproute syntax of `ip route add x.x.x.x/32 via 172.16.0.1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> > > > post-up route add -net XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 172.16.0.1
> > > >          remove post-up and change it to "up"

up route add -net XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 172.16.0.1
after that, ifdown em1:0 and ifup em1:0
or u can restart networking.service
cheer.